# using gridsplitter to split two columns with width set to * in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

So, I have a very weird problem. I have a grid with column definitions like below

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I have the main XAML as below:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0"/>
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"/>
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2"/>
```

This code causes a weird problem. When I move the splitter, both column 0 and column 2 starts resizing. I can always set width to "Auto" in both columns. But then, both scrollviewer take space as needed, when the page loads for the first time.

I want both scrollviewers to take half screen when page loads, with the option for user to change the size. Basically something similar to Window snapping. How can I achieve that here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you reserve the middle column just for the `GridSplitter`. The problem here is you need to change the `ResizeBehavior` of the `GridSplitter` to `PreviousAndNext` to change size of the 2 columns aside instead of the default `BasedOnAlignment`:

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Background="Green" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>
```

In fact the default value of `BasedOnAlignment` will behave OK if the horizontal and vertical size is stretch, so we don't need to specify the `ResizeBehavior` explicitly:

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Background="Green" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              />
```